# Python File Handling bad format display

Tags: python

I have written the following code to read a CSV file into parallel arrays. The code is working fine but the format of the display is not showing under appropriate columns. Is there any way to output data in a good format? I have used tab characters to give spaces between columns but it doesn't help. Thanks.

**Code**

```
def readFile():
  name = []
  dateofPurchase = []
  numberofTickets = []
  price = []

  file = open("sales.csv","r")
  for line in file:
    data =  line.split(",")
    name.append(data[0].strip())
    dateofPurchase.append(data[1].strip())
    numberofTickets.append(data[2].strip())
    price.append(data[3].strip())
  input("Data read...Press any key to continue")
  return name, dateofPurchase, numberofTickets,price

def displayContents(name, dateofPurchase, numberofTickets,price):
  print(f"Name \t \t Date of Purchase \t \t Number of Tickets \t \t Price")
  for counter in range(len(name)):
    print(f"{name[counter]} \t \t {dateofPurchase[counter]} \t \t{numberofTickets[counter]} \t \t {price[counter]}")

def main():
  name, dateofPurchase, numberofTickets,price = readFile()
  displayContents(name, dateofPurchase, numberofTickets,price)

main()
```

**output**

```
Name         Date of Purchase        Number of Tickets       Price
Deana Elbourne       19/04/2018         3        120
Allister Mothersdale         14/05/2018         1        50
Adriena Storton          09/06/2018         1        60
Darrin Betts         14/05/2018         4        360
Ellery Polak         02/08/2018         1        40
Genevieve Van den Broek          16/07/2018         1        50
Valeria Thundercliffe        20/08/2018         1        60
Marcellus Dowdeswell         25/08/2018         1        90
Maxine Rushforth         24/05/2018         2        80
Merissa Ahmad        30/06/2018         1        50
Nanice Shilburne         12/05/2018         1        40
Fina Gooders         27/07/2018         4        200
Arley McRobbie       27/06/2018         3        180
Imelda Sackler       23/06/2018         3        270
Bessie Coverly       01/05/2018         2        80
Morse Bazire         14/04/2018         3        150
Chris Barke          22/03/2018         4        240
Charlton Chafney         27/08/2018         1        90
Bart Harburtson          11/08/2018         1        50
Costanza Kinghorn        18/04/2018         3        180
Rhona Kittless       18/05/2018         4        360
Maiga Adhams         10/04/2018         2        80
Jacynth Corish       02/04/2018         4        200
Claudine Dansken         24/07/2018         3        180
Rodrick Shakesby         06/06/2018         4        360
Jacinthe Panketh         30/07/2018         2        80
Tomas Faraday        14/06/2018         4        160
Kennie Yeudall       31/07/2018         3        150
Tabbie Courteney         06/08/2018         3        180
Cayla Rosenbusch         04/08/2018         2        80
Hurlee Mion          18/08/2018         2        80
Michelina Fox        24/06/2018         1        40
Dunn Briand          12/08/2018         1        40
Patrizius Adamek         04/05/2018         4        200
Katrine Jeanin       22/06/2018         4        240
Hamnet Rule          23/05/2018         1        90
Moria Wyllie         21/08/2018         3        120
Jacklyn Paylie       28/03/2018         4        200
Ulrike Bottrell          02/07/2018         2        120
Camila Colston       31/07/2018         2        180
Arly Striker         12/08/2018         3        180
Casi Maystone        02/05/2018         4        360
```

Comment: Try `prettytable`: https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use prettytable, or tabulate. They make the job easier. If not, here is a homemade version. To read the CSV format, I use the `csv` library, which handles the format for me. I determine the maximum width of each column, so they have enough space.

```py
import csv


def main():
    rows = [["Name", "Date of Purchase", "Number of Tickets", "Price"]]
    with open("sales.csv") as stream:
        reader = csv.reader(stream, skipinitialspace=True)
        rows.extend(list(reader))

    # Calculate the widths for each column
    widths = [
        max(len(row[column_number]) for row in rows)
        for column_number, _ in enumerate(rows[0])
    ]

    print(f"Column widths: {widths}")  # Debug, can be deleted

    # Print the rows
    for row in rows:
        for cell, width in zip(row, widths):
            # Right align number, left align for the rest
            if cell.isdecimal():
                align = ">"
            else:
                align = "<"
            print(f"{cell:{align}{width}}", end=" | ")
        print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
Column widths: [23, 16, 17, 5]
Name                    | Date of Purchase | Number of Tickets | Price | 
Deana Elbourne          | 19/04/2018       |                 3 |   120 | 
Allister Mothersdale    | 14/05/2018       |                 1 |    50 | 
Adriena Storton         | 09/06/2018       |                 1 |    60 | 
Darrin Betts            | 14/05/2018       |                 4 |   360 | 
Ellery Polak            | 02/08/2018       |                 1 |    40 | 
Genevieve Van den Broek | 16/07/2018       |                 1 |    50 | 
Valeria Thundercliffe   | 20/08/2018       |                 1 |    60 | 
Marcellus Dowdeswell    | 25/08/2018       |                 1 |    90 | 
Maxine Rushforth        | 24/05/2018       |                 2 |    80 | 
Merissa Ahmad           | 30/06/2018       |                 1 |    50 | 
Nanice Shilburne        | 12/05/2018       |                 1 |    40 | 
Fina Gooders            | 27/07/2018       |                 4 |   200 | 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, which uses tabulate:

```py
import csv

import tabulate


def main():
    with open("sales.csv") as stream:
        reader = csv.reader(stream, skipinitialspace=True)
        rows = list(reader)

    headers = ["Name", "Date of Purchase", "Number of Tickets", "Price"]
    output = tabulate.tabulate(rows, headers=headers)
    print(output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
Name                     Date of Purchase      Number of Tickets    Price
-----------------------  ------------------  -------------------  -------
Deana Elbourne           19/04/2018                            3      120
Allister Mothersdale     14/05/2018                            1       50
Adriena Storton          09/06/2018                            1       60
Darrin Betts             14/05/2018                            4      360
Ellery Polak             02/08/2018                            1       40
Genevieve Van den Broek  16/07/2018                            1       50
Valeria Thundercliffe    20/08/2018                            1       60
Marcellus Dowdeswell     25/08/2018                            1       90
Maxine Rushforth         24/05/2018                            2       80
Merissa Ahmad            30/06/2018                            1       50
Nanice Shilburne         12/05/2018                            1       40
Fina Gooders             27/07/2018                            4      200
...
```